# What does epsilon mean here?

Tags: formal-languages, automata

I have an example with stack-machine here

[image]

What does epsilon mean here?

**P.S.** I don't have a textbook, there is just an example that I need to understand

Comment: Presumably, the empty string.

Comment: [empty string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language#:~:text=All%20finite%20languages%20are%20regular,as%20followed%20by%20several%20bs.)

Comment: For future reference you might want to note that in other sources you may find $\lambda$ used for the empty string.